# Keras: how to mutate data for each epoch

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to reduce overfitting by adding noise and random mutations to my original data.

I have a function that mutates training data

```
x, y = generate_data()
```

I would like the each epoch to call it and train my model on the new data. The hope is to reduce overfitting.

```
history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=100, batch_size=64)
```

What is the best way to change the data for each new epoch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess. Try:

```
for _ in range(num_epochs):
    x, y = generate_data()
    history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=1, batch_size=64)
```

Answer (score 0):

model.fit has a shuffle argument and the default value is True. So it shuffles the samples at each epoch.

```
def fit(self, x, y, batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=1, callbacks=None,
            validation_split=0., validation_data=None, shuffle=True,
            class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This only randomises the order of the data. I would like to mutate the data each time

Comment: As long as you keep your set balanced, `for _ in range(num_epochs):
    x, y = generate_data()
    history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=1, batch_size=64)` may work but I believe that your request would cause to delay the learning process of your model. It may even not be converged.